# I am unable to create query to get desired data frrom different tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have Four tables created in SQLite database

1. TaskTable : _id , user_id, title,description,project_id,position_id
2. SelectedTagTable : _id,task_id
3. PositionTable : _id,name
4. ProjectTable : _id , name , position_id

Now i have the following where clause for filtering data that is

> Where (user_id = 0) AND (SelectedTagTable.task_id = TaskTable._id) AND (TaskTable.position_id = PositionTable._id) AND (TaskTable.project_id = ProjectTable._id)

This is the query (where clause is same as mentioned above) `SELECT * FROM taskTable tk,selectedTagTable st, positionTable p, projectTable pp where tk.userId = 0 AND st.taskId = tk._id 
AND tk.position = p._id AND tk.project = pp._id ;` that i have made ... but im unable to convert it for android using SQLite functions

I need this query or code snippet for the android SQLite. Can any one create the query to get this filtered data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this return all the column for all the tables for user_id = 0

```
Select TaskTable.*, SelectedTagTable.*, PositionTable.*, ProjectTable.*
from TaskTable 
inner join SelectedTagTable on SelectedTagTable.task_id = TaskTable._id
inner join PositionTable on TaskTable.position_id = PositionTable._id  
inner join ProjectTable on TaskTable.project_id = ProjectTable._id
Where  user_id = 0
```

You need rawQuery method

```
  private final String MY_QUERY = "Select TaskTable.*, SelectedTagTable.*, PositionTable.*, ProjectTable,*
              from TaskTable 
              inner join SelectedTagTable on SelectedTagTable.task_id = TaskTable._id
              inner join PositionTable on TaskTable.position_id = PositionTable._id  
              inner join ProjectTable on TaskTable.project_id = ProjectTable._id
              Where  user_id = ?";


  db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{"0"});
```

Comment: do you have any idea that how i can use this query in android studio ..

Comment: this is the function to query database in android studio ......         Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, columns, whereArguments,whereArgumentsValues,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );

Comment: it sounds good let me try it .... Tell me one thing .. you typed  (ProjectTable,* ) did you mistakenly typed comma b/w them or instead of dot is used here.

Comment: Thumbs up for you (Y)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125437/discussion-between-nightcoder-and-scaisedge).